# Sort by Date key in my array of array containing objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, flatten

I have an array which contains several arrays, each containing several objects.

I need to sort the entire array(json_act_super) with key: Created(date in ascending order)

I tried to flatten the array and then sort by using following functions and various other methods but it did'nt worked

ex:

```
 var yourFlattenedArray = flatten(json_act_super);
 new_arr = new_arr.sort(yourFlattenedArray );

 function flatten(array) {
    return !Array.isArray(array) ? array : [].concat.apply([], 
    array.map(flatten));
    }
 function custom_sort(a, b) {
      return new Date(a.Created).getTime() - new 
      Date(b.Created).getTime();
   }

  var json_act_super= [[{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"12/1/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"11/1/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Marius Jaselskis","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"},{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"15/1/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"12/1/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Marius Jaselskis","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"},{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"24/1/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"23/1/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Laura Ivanauskaite","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"},{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"4/5/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"3/5/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Line Schøtt Jensen","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"},{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"15/5/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"14/5/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Kristina Ciegyte","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"},{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"8/3/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"7/3/2019","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Ana Moskaliova","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"},{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"25/3/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"22/3/2019","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Brigita Kapcinske","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"}],[{"Title":"Claim","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"15/10/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"9/10/2019","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Claim","ChangedBy":"Laura Kvedariene","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim2P8"}],[{"Title":"636619761964313943","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"22/5/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"15/5/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Mixed","ChangedBy":"Line Schøtt Jensen","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleProperty2P8"}],[{"Title":"636878973199308438","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"2/4/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"11/3/2019","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Mixed Follow Up DK","ChangedBy":"Helle Vinther Lorenzen","ActivityType":"ESTHA_FollowUponProperty2P8"}],[{"Title":"636514502410561268","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"16/1/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"13/1/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Mixed Urgent","ChangedBy":"Marianne Rohde","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandlePropertyUrgent2P8"},{"Title":"636514502429795141","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"16/1/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"13/1/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Mixed Urgent","ChangedBy":"Marianne Rohde","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandlePropertyUrgent2P8"},{"Title":"636876411401152914","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"11/3/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"8/3/2019","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Mixed Urgent","ChangedBy":"Kim Boysen","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandlePropertyUrgent2P8"},{"Title":"636891115107285634","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"26/3/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"25/3/2019","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Mixed Urgent","ChangedBy":"Helle Vinther Lorenzen","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandlePropertyUrgent2P8"}],[{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"1/2/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"4/1/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Anmeld krav","ChangedBy":"Kristina Ciegyte","ActivityType":"ESTHA_SubmitClaimP8"}],[{"Title":"636793139973643792","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"7/1/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"2/12/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Opflgning  6 mneder","ChangedBy":"RPA task 1750 PEH 3860 Closing manual remind 6 months follow up activities","ActivityType":"Opfølgning - 6 måneder"}]]
```

flattining and sorting is'nt working.Kindly help on how can i sort the entire thing in chronological order(sorted by Date created)

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten the array (You can use built in [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/flat) method), and then use `sort` method to sort in ascending order:

```js
var json_act_super= [[{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"12/1/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"11/1/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Marius Jaselskis","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"},{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"15/1/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"12/1/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Marius Jaselskis","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"},{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"24/1/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"23/1/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Laura Ivanauskaite","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"},{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"4/5/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"3/5/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Line Schøtt Jensen","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"},{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"15/5/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"14/5/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Kristina Ciegyte","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"},{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"8/3/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"7/3/2019","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Ana Moskaliova","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"},{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"25/3/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"22/3/2019","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Handle Mail 1","ChangedBy":"Brigita Kapcinske","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim1P8"}],[{"Title":"Claim","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"15/10/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"9/10/2019","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Claim","ChangedBy":"Laura Kvedariene","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleClaim2P8"}],[{"Title":"636619761964313943","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"22/5/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"15/5/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Mixed","ChangedBy":"Line Schøtt Jensen","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandleProperty2P8"}],[{"Title":"636878973199308438","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"2/4/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"11/3/2019","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Mixed Follow Up DK","ChangedBy":"Helle Vinther Lorenzen","ActivityType":"ESTHA_FollowUponProperty2P8"}],[{"Title":"636514502410561268","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"16/1/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"13/1/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Mixed Urgent","ChangedBy":"Marianne Rohde","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandlePropertyUrgent2P8"},{"Title":"636514502429795141","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"16/1/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"13/1/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Mixed Urgent","ChangedBy":"Marianne Rohde","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandlePropertyUrgent2P8"},{"Title":"636876411401152914","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"11/3/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"8/3/2019","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Mixed Urgent","ChangedBy":"Kim Boysen","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandlePropertyUrgent2P8"},{"Title":"636891115107285634","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"26/3/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"25/3/2019","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/x Mixed Urgent","ChangedBy":"Helle Vinther Lorenzen","ActivityType":"ESTHA_HandlePropertyUrgent2P8"}],[{"Title":"1008320604ELSEFALSIG_1008320604","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"1/2/2018","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"4/1/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Anmeld krav","ChangedBy":"Kristina Ciegyte","ActivityType":"ESTHA_SubmitClaimP8"}],[{"Title":"636793139973643792","CaseID":1575274,"DueDate":"7/1/2019","StatusValue":"Finished","ActivityText":null,"Created":"2/12/2018","Path":"/sites/estate/Lists/Opflgning  6 mneder","ChangedBy":"RPA task 1750 PEH 3860 Closing manual remind 6 months follow up activities","ActivityType":"Opfølgning - 6 måneder"}]];

const flattedArray = json_act_super.flat(2);

flattedArray.sort((a, b) => {
   a = a['Created'].split('/');
   b = b['Created'].split('/');
   return a[2] - b[2] || a[1] - b[1] || a[0] - b[0];
});
 
console.log(JSON.stringify(flattedArray, null, 4));
```

Comment: Hi...This solution works perfectly great in console but not in code.Any idea why would it be like that?

Comment: Remember that this solution is assuming your date format is DD/MM/YYYY, if the format is different is not going to sort correctly